# How do we know when "どんどん" includes a notion of speed?

Tags: meaning

How do we know when "どんどん" includes a notion of speed?

> ある種の動物は**どんどん**数が減ってきている。
>   Certain animals are fast disappearing.

Here it's something(continuous and) fast.

> 霧が**どんどん**濃くなっている。
>   The fog is growing thicker.

Here it just tells that it's something growing in a regular manner but the speed is normal.

How can we conclude which meaning is the good one? Sometimes the context could not be sufficient because of the nature of this difference.

Comment: What is your basis for saying that the どんどん in the second sentence just tells us that it's growing in a regular manner, but the speed is normal? A quick Google search suggests the sentence and translation are from the Tanaka corpus; corpus translated sentences are not always perfectly accurate. It seems more likely to me that the translator took liberties here than that どんどん stopped meaning what it typically means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ある種{しゅ}の動物{どうぶつ}はどんどん数{かず}が減{へ}ってきている。
>   Certain animals are **fast** disappearing.
>
> 霧{きり}がどんどん濃{こ}くなっている。
>   The fog is growing thicker.

In both sentences, 「どんどん」 means the exact same thing, which is "***increasingly***", "***progressively***", etc.

Someone (or is it you?) happened to use the word "***fast***" in translating the first sentence, but that does not mean that the first sentence focuses more on speed than the second.

"Speed" may be implied by 「どんどん」 in the sense that it is often used to describe the changes that are taking place more rapidly than one might expect.  Unless expressed by other words in the context, however, 「どんどん」, all by itself, does not particularly include a strong notion of speed.

Comment: To add to this, there is also [段々]{だんだん}, which is essentially the same as どんどん, but slower.

Comment: ^ essentially the same -- えっ? ( ﾟДﾟ)　"rapidly" = "gradually" ?  　 ◎「どんどん食べて！」✖「」だんだん食べて」！◎「どんどんお客さんが来る」✖「だんだんお客さんが来る」◎「仕事がどんどんはかどる」✖「仕事がだんだんはかどる」